# SIM5320 Arduino GPRS shield with MQTT

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, gprs, sim900

The new arduino GPRS/GSM 3g shield says that it has MQTT support with AT commands. However, each command that I've tried from the [official documentation](http://www.microchip.ua/simcom/WCDMA/APPNOTES/SIMCom_3G_MQTT_Application%20Note_V1.00.pdf) has returned an error and every other person on the internet has reported the same thing.

I have been using the adafruit fona library to run it and everything that it offers works on my board. As it's very new though, it doesn't have any MQTT implementation.

I know that the SIM900 chip has libraries for MQTT, but they don't work with the SIM5320. Does anyone have any advice on where to start for getting this chip to run MQTT?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly is  the "returned an error"?

Comment: which modules (SIM5320A/ SIM5320E/ SIM5320J) and what firmware version is used in the setup?

Answer (score 0):

At the end it is done via TCP. So if you establish a TCP connection and send the MQTT "connect" and "publish" messages, you should be able to connect and publish.

Here you can find a library that worked for me: https://github.com/andyduino/MQTT-for-SIM900/tree/master/libraries/mqtt

Instead of using "AT+CIPSTART" on SIM900 you will need to use "AT+CIPOPEN" on SIM5320, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice arduino library that you can adapt to use with your module. Its specifically for SIM800. Your module may take slightly different AT commands, so all you would have to do is change the commands. Here's a link to the library ->
https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/arduino-mqtt-library-for-sim800-gsm-modem/

Be warned, it will take some time and effort to adapt this to your module. But I'm pretty sure its as simple as swapping out some AT commands. I hope this helps you.